# springboot external configuration - profile specific configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-boot-configuration

According to the SpringBoot documentation, the order of configuration is as:

> Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
>
> Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
>
> Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
>
> Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).

On my project I have a profile called "prod" and the following files:

- application.yml (inside the jar)
- application-prod.yml (inside the jar)

And I also want to override some of the properties using an external file. Since according to the docs, an external `application.yml` will be overridden by the internal `application-prod.yml`, I need to make sure that the external file is considered as a `profile specific` config file.

I have tried to use:

`-Dspring.config.location=<my path>/application-prod.yml`

and I have also tried:

`-Dspring.config.location=file:<my path>/application-prod.yml`

In all cases I get the value from the **internal** `application-prod.yml`

If I totally remove the internal config file then I get the value from the external (so I know that the config picks up the file).

I understand that this external file is considered as the equivalent to the generic `application.yml` and not a profile specific.

How can I configure it to be considered as a profile specific external config?

Comment: Why not just name it `application-prod.yml`? Instead of trying to hack around it.

Comment: I have named it `application-prod.yml` . It is just that spring's parameter `Dspring.config.location` ignores this is a profile specific config and considers it as a generic one. How do I specify this is a profile-specific? I'm trying to follow the order or rules as per the docs, not hack around it

Comment: You are overthinking it you don't need the `spring.config.location`. It will already override what you want.

Comment: @M.Deinum Probably you haven't understood my question. I need the "spring.config.location" to pass the location of the external files

Comment: If it is in the same location as the jar you don't and if you want a location then specify a location NOT a full path to the file use only the directory (`file:<my-path>/` spring boot will detect the `application.yml` etc) this is also clearly stated in the documentation. > *Files specified in spring.config.location are used as-is, with no support for profile-specific variants, and are overridden by any profile-specific properties.*

Comment: @M.Deinum Just saw your answer. Already solved it. I was setting the directory path in the parameter but it was not ending in `/` . It should be written a bit more clearly in the docs or at least have an example...

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

You need to use a `Directory` externally to set the profile specific configuration files, not using the file directly and it needs to end in `/`. So it has to be:

`-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`

`-Dspring.config.location=/<some-path>/config/` (any path that ends in `/`)

and in there have a :

`application-prod.yml`