# Externalize password in Spring Boot properties file

Tags: spring-boot

i have application.properties file

which has

```
spring.profiles.active=local
```

and i have application-local.properties which has many fields including

```
api.password = password123
```

As you can see i have hard coded password123 in properties file.

Suppose i am on windows and i have app.properties file on windows which has

```
 api.password = password123
```

And i want to read  api.password in spring boot properties file through app.properties

How can i achieve it ?

Comment: Where is the difference ? You don't gain more security just by adding a second file

Comment: do you want to read only that property? or all properties from `app.properties` file?

Comment: Maybe you can put the password in your environment variables

Comment: @Marged i do I wont be app.properties to my GIT HUB It would be on Linux machine for each environment i.e DEV,UAT AND PROD

Comment: @Deadpool I just want to externalize api.password

Comment: I would suggest keep property in you application.yml only however when you start your application you can password from command line like java -jar -Dapi.password=mysecretpassword myApp.jar (you can also create bat/.sh file for it) but using it only on command line will ensure password is nowhere lying on machine

Comment: i don't need theory .i need the syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [springboot external configuration - profile specific configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186918/springboot-external-configuration-profile-specific-configuration)

Answer (score 4):

### Startup parameters

If you want to read properties from a non-standard location, you can start your application with `--spring.config.location` or with `--spring.config.additional-location` parameters.

```
$ java -jar app.jar --spring.config.location=file:./app.properties
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files

### @PropertySource

If you don't control startup parameters, you can use `@PropertySource` annotation.
Simply annotate your main class (or any other configuration):

```
 @PropertySource("file:.app.properties")
```

You can set `ignoreResourceNotFound=true`, so the application will start, even if the file is not there.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html

#### Read the documentation

There are literally **17 ways** to pass properties to a Spring-Boot application.

I suggest, you get familiar with the convention, as it is crucial to understand which file takes a precedence:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use --spring.config.location like below

$ java -jar myApp.jar --spring.config.location=file:/directoryof file/app.properties

Comment: If you are sure only then answer.Your technique won;'t work

Comment: This way are you able to load properties file?

Comment: If you want to read out of your classpath this is the only way. As you are using profile so you have to use $ java -jar myApp.jar --spring.config.name=app --spring.config.location=file:/propertfilefoldername

Comment: @OracleMonkey it works, you should honor that people try to help you

Answer (score 0):

i used jasypt : https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot
to encrypt the password, then you supply a decryption string (jasypt.encryptor.password) as startup parameter. That way no useabel password is in the configuration and on the git-repos.....